# Windows command line: start /wait wordpad

Tags: windows, command-line

Hi, when I run the following BAT file, it doesn't wait for Wordpad to terminate.  Notepad starts immediately.  How can I make it wait?  I am using 64-bit Windows 7.

```
REM Close notepad.
taskkill /im notepad.exe /f
REM Start Wordpad and wait until it terminates.
start /wait write.exe C:\Users\dell\Downloads\test.txt
REM Restart Notepad.
start notepad.exe C:\Users\dell\Downloads\test2.txt
PAUSE
```

Comment: I think it is something about wordpad. I changed wordpad with iexplore and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A perfect question for [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)!

On my system (also Windows 7), write.exe actually starts up the wordpad.exe process and then exits. Since your "start /wait" is only waiting on write.exe, it returns as soon as write.exe exits.

[image: procmon screen]

If you do "start /wait wordpad.exe ...", it should indeed wait until wordpad exits.

Answer (score 0):

start /wait notepad && start wordpad

Comment: Can you please explain why this should help!?